# Change text in multiple html elements with same class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got links in one wrapper which have specific class. I know that i can change text with .text() in jQuery, but what if i have 2 or more texts in same class. How can I change them all at once ?

Comment: Where is the script?

Comment: use class selector in jquery to change all

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's not correct `$('.someClass').text('new text')` will change all. You are thinking about `text()` as getter but in fact that' will actually return all text in collection concatenated together . It's  a weird one compared to all other getters

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, that is right. Just misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all to  same new string.

```
$('.someClass').text('new text');
```

Loop over all in class and modify existing text for each element

```
$('.someClass').text(function(_, oldText){
    return oldText + ' new text'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help to change multiple HTML elements with same class with jquery

```js
$(function () {
    $(".change-title").on("click", function (e) {
        $('.change-text').text($(this).data("desc"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-text">
   Change Text 1
</div>

<p class="change-text">Change Text 1</p>
<a href="#" class="change-title" data-desc=" Change Text 1">button1</a>

<a href="#"  class="change-title" data-desc=" Change Text 2">button 2</a>
```

Comment: can you convert the jquery to use es6/vanilla JS?